# sql case when in python

Tags: python, sql, case-when

how to write this in python:

This is my code sample:

```
set "Full_Year_Goal" =
case
    when ("Start_Date" = '2014-07-27' or "Start_Date" = '2014-07-27') and "End_Date" = '2015-07-25' then 'Y'
    when ("Start_Date" = '2015-07-26' or "Start_Date" = '2015-07-27') and "End_Date" = '2016-07-30' then 'Y'
    when ("Start_Date" = '2016-07-31') and "End_Date" = '2017-07-29' then 'Y'
    when ("Start_Date" = '2017-07-30' or "Start_Date" = '2017-07-31') and "End_Date" = '2018-07-28' then 'Y'
    else 'N' end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the guidelines on how to post the Question in SO.  We are not clear what you are trying to ask here

Comment: i want to write this sql query in python to make a new variable Full_Year_Goal

Comment: Can you edit this post with what you tried ?

Answer (score 3):

Here we go:

```
def getLetter(startDate, endDate):

    if startDate == 'something' && endDate == 'something2':
        return "Y"
    elif startDate == 'somethingElse' && endDate == 'something2':
        return "N"
    else:
        return None

fullYearGoal = getLetter("2014", "2015")
```

Comment: i have two start dates and one end date, should i use or in if statement

Comment: You can customize it whatever you want. You can define an "and" by `&&` and an "or" by `||`

Comment: def getLetter():
    startDate = None
    endDate = None

    if Gs_Start_Date == '2014-07-27' | '2014-07-27' && endDate == '2015-07-25':
        return "Y"
    elif Gs_Start_Date == '2015-07-26' | '2015-07-27' && endDate == '2016-07-30':
        return "Y"
    elif Gs_Start_Date == '2016-07-31' && endDate == '2017-07-29':
        return "Y"
    elif Gs_Start_Date == '2017-07-30' | '2017-07-31' && endDate == '2018-07-28':
        return "Y"
    else:
        return "N"          did not worked

Comment: i have a dataframe where start_date and end_date are columns and based on particular values in these columns , I want to make a flag column - full year goal

Comment: Neither `&&` nor `||` are valid python operators. Use `and` and `or` instead.

Comment: I searched for an hour to find the solution @LingVu, thanks!